# yii queue doesn't detect jobs in database

Tags: yii2, queue, esp8266

I'm trying to run a queue using yii so I can do some tests, but whenever I type the command yii queue/run, no job seems to be put in waiting,

This is to send the information of an ID and status of a job that when the conditions are met, will be ran in the main page

This is the code that sends the data into the queue:

```
class HorarioController extends Controller
{
public function actionBuscar()
{
    $hora = date("H").":00".":00";
    $dia = date("N");
 $horarios = Horarios_Equipos::find()->all();

    foreach($horarios as $horario)
    {

        echo $horario->id_equipo."\n";
        echo $horario->estado."\n";
        //enviar a cola

        Yii::$app->queue->push(
            new HorarioJob([
                'id_equipo' => $horario->id_equipo,
                'estado' => $horario->estado,                   
            ])
        );
    }

    return ExitCode::OK;
}

}
```

And this is the code that does the action in the queue

```
public function execute($queue)
 {

if($estado == '1'){
    if($pin == 1)
   {
    $equipo = Equipos::find()->where(['id'=>$id])->one();
    $equipo->estado = '1';
    $equipo->save ();

    $curl = new curl\Curl();

    $response = $curl->get($equipo->ip.'/gpio/LEDa=ON');

    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $id]);
}
    elseif ($pin == 2)
{
    $equipo = Equipos::find()->where(['id'=>$id])->one();
    $equipo->estado = '1';
    $equipo->save ();

    $curl = new curl\Curl();

    $response = $curl->get($equipo->ip.'/gpio/LEDb=ON');

    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $id]);
}

    elseif ($pin == 3)
{
    $equipo = Equipos::find()->where(['id'=>$id])->one();
    $equipo->estado = '1';
    $equipo->save ();

    $curl = new curl\Curl();

    $response = $curl->get($equipo->ip.'/gpio/LEDc=ON');

    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $id]);
}
    elseif ($pin == 4)
{
    $equipo = Equipos::find()->where(['id'=>$id])->one();
    $equipo->estado = '1';
    $equipo->save ();

    $curl = new curl\Curl();

    $response = $curl->get($equipo->ip.'/gpio/LEDd=ON');

    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $id]);
}



    }       

if ($estado == 0){

    if ($pin == '1')
    {
    $equipo = Equipos::find()->where(['id'=>$id])->one();
    $equipo->estado = '0';
    $equipo->save ();

    $curl = new curl\Curl();

    $response = $curl->get($equipo->ip.'/gpio/LEDa=OFF');

    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $id]);
}

    if ($pin == '2')
{
    $equipo = Equipos::find()->where(['id'=>$id])->one();
    $equipo->estado = '0';
    $equipo->save ();

    $curl = new curl\Curl();

    $response = $curl->get($equipo->ip.'/gpio/LEDb=OFF');

    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $id]);
}

    if ($pin == '3')
{
    $equipo = Equipos::find()->where(['id'=>$id])->one();
    $equipo->estado = '0';
    $equipo->save ();

    $curl = new curl\Curl();

    $response = $curl->get($equipo->ip.'/gpio/LEDc=OFF');

    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $id]);
}

    if ($pin == '4')
{
    $equipo = Equipos::find()->where(['id'=>$id])->one();
    $equipo->estado = '0';
    $equipo->save ();

    $curl = new curl\Curl();

    $response = $curl->get($equipo->ip.'/gpio/LEDd=OFF');

    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $id]);
}

    }


}
}
```

This is what shows when I run yii queue/run:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\accontrol>yii queue/run

C:\xampp\htdocs\accontrol>
```

And if I run yii queue/info it only shows this:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\accontrol>yii queue/info
Jobs
- waiting: 0
- delayed: 0
- reserved: 0
- done: 0
```

As fas as I know the files where the queue functions are written are correct and I should be able to run the queue/run command, at least get an error to see where I'm wrong, but it just doesn't

Comment: Does `./yii queue/run --verbose` shows anything (you need to push job to queue first)?

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\accontrol>yii queue/run -v
     2019-06-14 23:50:12 [pid: 9320] - Worker is started
     2019-06-14 23:50:12 [pid: 9320] - Worker is stopped (0:00:00)

Comment: You don't have any jobs in your queue. Are you sure you've pushed them correctly?

Comment: As far as I know, the code is written correctly where it should push the jobs into the database, but its not doing it, i've seen many examples of the code but they're all written the same, I don't know what would be different

Comment: Is there a way to know when the code isn't pushing the jobs? that seems to be the problem but I can't know if its pushing them or not

Comment: Debug bar has panel for pushed jobs.

Comment: Debug bar?, how do I open it?

Comment: Quick note, I'm coding on Sublime Text 3 and whenever I plugin the device I use I get this error: Error trying to parse file: Invalid codepoint in Packages\User\Stino\serials\Main.sublime-menu:10:44, Not sure if this will impact anything on the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, PHP had the timezone configured incorrectly so when it tried to search for the time on the database it wouldn't match with the time it had configured, had to modify the php.ini document to set the correct timezone, If you're having this problem to enter the php.ini document you can do it via the control panel: in the Apache section click the config button and select the     PHP(php.ini)
Then use the find option and search for timezone, and then you may type the timezone of your area, in my case its America/Mexico_City
Heres the link where you can find the timezones: https://www.php.net/manual/es/timezones.php